# how to block backspace of AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, onkeylistener

how to block backspace of AutoCompleteTextView Android. Or how to override onKeyListener for block the same.

Comment: Do you want to disable backspace?

Comment: block backspace? how do you want to correct some typos entered then?

Comment: @Piyush yes. i want to disable backspace

Comment: @pskink: i have implemented close button at right side of auot completeTextView.

Comment: @Vinay call _return true_ in _onKeyListener_ method